# How to unify the time format in r?

Tags: r

I have a dataset `test`. It was like  `30-06-22 23:55:00`, `1/7/2022 0:00 AM` in excel, I have no idea why there are two different formats in one column and I can't change the format in excel. It's weird because the time format of each month from the 1st to the 12th is different from the rest of the days. Therefore, I import the data to R and try to unify the formats by using `parse_date_time()` function. But now it changed to `44568"` in R. And I got `Warning message: 20737 failed to parse.`  after running the code `test$Time<- parse_date_time(test$Time, orders= c("%d-%m-%y %H%M%S","%d/%m/%Y %I:%M:%S %p" ))`

I was so confused about why the formats are different and how to unify the data formats in the same way like `1/7/2022 0:00 AM` `(d/m/Y H:M AM/PM)`

```
    test<- c("30-06-22 20:35:00", "30-06-22 20:40:00", "30-06-22 20:45:00", 
"30-06-22 20:50:00", "30-06-22 20:55:00", "30-06-22 21:00:00", 
"30-06-22 21:05:00", "30-06-22 21:10:00", "30-06-22 21:15:00", 
"30-06-22 21:20:00", "30-06-22 21:25:00", "30-06-22 21:30:00", 
"30-06-22 21:35:00", "30-06-22 21:40:00", "30-06-22 21:45:00", 
"30-06-22 21:50:00", "30-06-22 21:55:00", "30-06-22 22:00:00", 
"30-06-22 22:05:00", "30-06-22 22:10:00", "30-06-22 22:15:00", 
"30-06-22 22:20:00", "30-06-22 22:25:00", "30-06-22 22:30:00", 
"30-06-22 22:35:00", "30-06-22 22:40:00", "30-06-22 22:45:00", 
"30-06-22 22:50:00", "30-06-22 22:55:00", "30-06-22 23:00:00", 
"30-06-22 23:05:00", "30-06-22 23:10:00", "30-06-22 23:15:00", 
"30-06-22 23:20:00", "30-06-22 23:25:00", "30-06-22 23:30:00", 
"30-06-22 23:35:00", "30-06-22 23:40:00", "30-06-22 23:45:00", 
"30-06-22 23:50:00", "30-06-22 23:55:00", "44568", "44568.003472222219", 
"44568.006944444445", "44568.010416666664", "44568.013888888891", 
"44568.017361111109", "44568.020833333336", "44568.024305555555", 
"44568.027777777781", "44568.03125", "44568.034722222219", "44568.038194444445", 
"44568.041666666664", "44568.045138888891", "44568.048611111109", 
"44568.052083333336", "44568.055555555555", "44568.059027777781", 
"44568.0625", "44568.065972222219", "44568.069444444445", "44568.072916666664", 
"44568.076388888891", "44568.079861111109", "44568.083333333336", 
"44568.086805555555", "44568.090277777781", "44568.09375", "44568.097222222219", 
"44568.100694444445", "44568.104166666664", "44568.107638888891", 
"44568.111111111109", "44568.114583333336", "44568.118055555555", 
"44568.121527777781", "44568.125", "44568.128472222219", "44568.131944444445", 
"44568.135416666664", "44568.138888888891", "44568.142361111109", 
"44568.145833333336", "44568.149305555555", "44568.152777777781", 
"44568.15625", "44568.159722222219", "44568.163194444445", "44568.166666666664", 
"44568.170138888891", "44568.173611111109", "44568.177083333336", 
"44568.180555555555", "44568.184027777781", "44568.1875", "44568.190972222219", 
"44568.194444444445", "44568.197916666664", "44568.201388888891", 
"44568.204861111109")
```

Comment: That's a super weird error that I have ever met. I saved the excel as a  `csv`  file and then all the `Time`  formats were imported properly without changing to numbers. And the ` parse_date_time` works to unify the `Time` formats in one column.

Answer (score 0):

We may do

```
library(parsedate)
library(dplyr)
v1 <- as.numeric(test)
v1 <- coalesce(openxlsx::convertToDateTime(v1), parse_date(test))
v1
```

-output

```
[> v1
  [1] "2022-06-30 20:35:00 UTC" "2022-06-30 20:40:00 UTC" "2022-06-30 20:45:00 UTC" "2022-06-30 20:50:00 UTC" "2022-06-30 20:55:00 UTC" "2022-06-30 21:00:00 UTC"
  [7] "2022-06-30 21:05:00 UTC" "2022-06-30 21:10:00 UTC" "2022-06-30 21:15:00 UTC" "2022-06-30 21:20:00 UTC" "2022-06-30 21:25:00 UTC" "2022-06-30 21:30:00 UTC"
 [13] "2022-06-30 21:35:00 UTC" "2022-06-30 21:40:00 UTC" "2022-06-30 21:45:00 UTC" "2022-06-30 21:50:00 UTC" "2022-06-30 21:55:00 UTC" "2022-06-30 22:00:00 UTC"
 [19] "2022-06-30 22:05:00 UTC" "2022-06-30 22:10:00 UTC" "2022-06-30 22:15:00 UTC" "2022-06-30 22:20:00 UTC" "2022-06-30 22:25:00 UTC" "2022-06-30 22:30:00 UTC"
 [25] "2022-06-30 22:35:00 UTC" "2022-06-30 22:40:00 UTC" "2022-06-30 22:45:00 UTC" "2022-06-30 22:50:00 UTC" "2022-06-30 22:55:00 UTC" "2022-06-30 23:00:00 UTC"
 [31] "2022-06-30 23:05:00 UTC" "2022-06-30 23:10:00 UTC" "2022-06-30 23:15:00 UTC" "2022-06-30 23:20:00 UTC" "2022-06-30 23:25:00 UTC" "2022-06-30 23:30:00 UTC"
 [37] "2022-06-30 23:35:00 UTC" "2022-06-30 23:40:00 UTC" "2022-06-30 23:45:00 UTC" "2022-06-30 23:50:00 UTC" "2022-06-30 23:55:00 UTC" "2022-01-07 05:00:00 UTC"
 [43] "2022-01-07 05:05:00 UTC" "2022-01-07 05:10:00 UTC" "2022-01-07 05:15:00 UTC" "2022-01-07 05:20:00 UTC" "2022-01-07 05:25:00 UTC" "2022-01-07 05:30:00 UTC"
 [49] "2022-01-07 05:35:00 UTC" "2022-01-07 05:40:00 UTC" "2022-01-07 05:45:00 UTC" "2022-01-07 05:50:00 UTC" "2022-01-07 05:55:00 UTC" "2022-01-07 06:00:00 UTC"
 [55] "2022-01-07 06:05:00 UTC" "2022-01-07 06:10:00 UTC" "2022-01-07 06:15:00 UTC" "2022-01-07 06:20:00 UTC" "2022-01-07 06:25:00 UTC" "2022-01-07 06:30:00 UTC"
 [61] "2022-01-07 06:35:00 UTC" "2022-01-07 06:40:00 UTC" "2022-01-07 06:45:00 UTC" "2022-01-07 06:50:00 UTC" "2022-01-07 06:55:00 UTC" "2022-01-07 07:00:00 UTC"
 [67] "2022-01-07 07:05:00 UTC" "2022-01-07 07:10:00 UTC" "2022-01-07 07:15:00 UTC" "2022-01-07 07:20:00 UTC" "2022-01-07 07:25:00 UTC" "2022-01-07 07:30:00 UTC"
 [73] "2022-01-07 07:35:00 UTC" "2022-01-07 07:40:00 UTC" "2022-01-07 07:45:00 UTC" "2022-01-07 07:50:00 UTC" "2022-01-07 07:55:00 UTC" "2022-01-07 08:00:00 UTC"
 [79] "2022-01-07 08:05:00 UTC" "2022-01-07 08:10:00 UTC" "2022-01-07 08:15:00 UTC" "2022-01-07 08:20:00 UTC" "2022-01-07 08:25:00 UTC" "2022-01-07 08:30:00 UTC"
 [85] "2022-01-07 08:35:00 UTC" "2022-01-07 08:40:00 UTC" "2022-01-07 08:45:00 UTC" "2022-01-07 08:50:00 UTC" "2022-01-07 08:55:00 UTC" "2022-01-07 09:00:00 UTC"
 [91] "2022-01-07 09:05:00 UTC" "2022-01-07 09:10:00 UTC" "2022-01-07 09:15:00 UTC" "2022-01-07 09:20:00 UTC" "2022-01-07 09:25:00 UTC" "2022-01-07 09:30:00 UTC"
 [97] "2022-01-07 09:35:00 UTC" "2022-01-07 09:40:00 UTC" "2022-01-07 09:45:00 UTC" "2022-01-07 09:50:00 UTC" "2022-01-07 09:55:00 UTC"
```

Comment: No, as you can see it changed to the wrong time. "2023-01-11 12:30:18 UTC" should be "2022-07-01 00:00:00 UTC"

Comment: `convertToDateTime`  function didn't work correctly, It changed month and day as well as other mistakes were found in my case.

Comment: And I can't simply use `as.numeric` function as there were two different time formats in one column, `NAs introduced by coercion`.

Comment: sorry for the misleading information. I want to change the whole column to the format like `d/m/Y H: M AM/PM

Comment: Yeah, it's a warning message, which also means that all the time formats like `30-06-22 23:55:00` were changed to NAs.

Comment: That's the most confusing part, in the excel file, the `Time` column has two different formats `30-06-22 23:55:00`  and `1/7/2022 0:00 AM`. I have no idea why there are two different formats and I want to unify them. Then I import this excel file to R, and all the data with the same format like `1/7/2022 0:00 AM` changed to numeric.....

Comment: @LEE You can check `coalesce(NA, 5)#[1] 5`

Answer (score 0):

#To unify the different date/time formats in one column.

```
test$Time<- parse_date_time(test$Time, orders= c("%m%d%Y %H%M","%d%m%Y %H%M","%m%d%Y %H%M%S","%d%m%Y %H%M%S","%d-%m-%y %H%M%S"))
```